# USB driver folder does not exist

Tags: android

I'm trying to debug an application on a device.

I am following this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

And I'm on Windows 7 and I'm installing a driver for the first time.

The problem is that I can't find my USB driver folder. It just doesn't exist on my pc.

The file directory is sdk\extras\google\usb_driver and the sdk doesn't exist.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

After you downloaded the Android SDK, where did you install it to?  That path is what `<sdk>` in the path `<sdk>\extras\google\usb_driver\` refers to.